Proving a sequence of functions is asymptotic
I have a sequence of functions $\{1,x,x^2 \ln x,x^2,x^3 \ln x,x^3, x^4 \ln x,... \}$
I want to prove this is asymptotic as $x \rightarrow 0^+$. My problem is that I don't know how to represent the sequence of functions in a simplified form. Would I have to use a piecewise function for odd and even values of $n$?
A sequence of functions is asymptotic as $x \rightarrow 0^+$ if whenever $n > m$ we have $ \phi_n(x)= o(\phi_m(x))$ as $x \rightarrow 0^+$

What you understand under "functions is asymptotic" ?

@zkutch Please check my edit.

@AdamRubinson Please check my edit.

What have you tried? As I see you have to simply check two cases.

@zkutch For even $n$ I know I have $x^{\frac{n}{2}}$. For odd $n$ I am struggling though (this is assuming we start at $n=1$ by the way not $n=0$).

@zkutch I don’t know how to write the other case if you could help me with that.

Let's start enumeration, as usually in mathematics, from $1$, so $\phi(1)=1, \phi(2)=x$ etc. Then, starting from $n=2$ we have, as you correctly have in comment $\phi(2k)=x^k$. For odd $n$, starting from $n=3$, let's observe following:
$$3 \quad 5 \quad 7 \cdots \ 2k+1\  \cdots \\ 
2 \quad 3 \quad 4 \cdots \ k+1\  \cdots  $$
where in first line are odd indexes, starting from $3$, for your sequence and in second line are powers for $x$. Now we come to formula for your sequence
$$\phi(n)=\begin{cases}1,   & n =1, \\
x^k, & n= 2k,&\ \ k=\overline{1,\infty}, \\
x^{k+1}\ln x, & n=2k+1,&\ \ k=\overline{1,\infty}
\end{cases}$$
Hope now you can easily deal with the asymptotic property that interests you, but write if you need help

Thank you. For the cases $n=2k$ and $n=2k+1$, it is easy. I just take the limit as $x \rightarrow 0^+$ of $\frac{x^{k+1}}{x^k} = x$ which tends to $0$ and also $\frac{x^{k+1} \ln(x)}{x^k \ln(x) = x}$ which tends to $0$ too.
However, for the case $n=1$ I am not sure how to handle this at all. Can I just ignore it because it is one term only which is the first term?

For each member with $>1$ of sequence we have  $1=1\cdot \phi(n) \cdot \frac{1}{ \phi(n)}$.

How does that help me?

As I see you need $\phi_n(x)= o(\phi_m(x))$, when $n>m$, right?

That's what I need yes.

So we can write $\phi(n) = 1 \cdot \phi(n)$ and if/when $\lim \phi(n) = 0$, then we have $\phi(n) =o(1)$.

Thanks. So $\phi_m(x) = 1$ in this case?

Of course, but write not as $\phi_m(x) = 1$, but as  $\phi_m(x) = o(1)$. Any other problem?

No that is everything. Thank you.
